# PHP/SQL - Check if a DB has any tables or not

Tags: php, database

How do I check if a created database has any tables added to it yet?
I'm not looking for values inside a table but just tables in general.

Is there an equivalent to 'SELECT 1 FROM db_table' kind of query or is there a php function that can check if any tables exist in a database?

What I want to achieve is something along the lines of:

```
if(db_doesn't_have_tables) { show message }
else { do something }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you :

```
SHOW TABLES FROM database
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` catalog views:

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

However all platforms will have better vendor-specific system tables for the purpose.